# Radio button gets deselected in the next fieldset

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, dom

I was creating a dynamic page with PHP and Laravel and had to make a few changes. One of them was to add another radio button option per each card. The code of the card is as follows:

```
<div class="card" style="margin:10px;">
    <img src="storage/1576967030.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Group A</h5>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">For 1 day</small></p>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="groupA">
            <p class="card-text">7.49€ <small class="text-muted"> Basic insurance</small></p>
        </label>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="groups" id="groupA" value="A" tabindex="0">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="groupAinsurance">
            <p class="card-text">14.99€ <small class="text-muted">Full insurance</small></p>
        </label>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="groups" id="groupAinsurance" value="A+insurance" tabindex="0">
    </div>
</div>
```

When I hit the "Next" button in my form, to proceed to the next fieldset, any option selected from any card, gets deselected.

Is there anything wrong that I'm not aware of?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
mikeysantana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that when you're hitting the 'Next' button, the HTML is getting reloaded, and by default, the options you mentioned aren't selected. When you hit 'Next', does the card you mention get removed from the page?

Comment: Oh no, I don't reload the page. The elements are removed from the page, as you said, with JS

Comment: Are you deleting the div, or are you doing something like: display:none? @MiguelSantana

Comment: I'm using jQuery's show() and hide() methods, so I would say the display:none

Comment: if you try to hide it manually, using something like: $("#cardToHide").css("display", "none"); will the options get deselected still? @MiguelSantana

Comment: Well... they do get recognized 'till the end and the server catches the value with the parameters as you said.

Comment: So, is it working this way? I believe jQuery's show and hide 'reload' the html in the background, that must be why it wasn't working before

Comment: Yes it is indeed! I'll check that and see what is possible, and change it accordingly. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem! Just make sure to mark this as answered for future visitors!